# rails nested forms issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I've been bashing my head against this nested forms issue for a week. I've read alot of posts and watched the railscast on the issue but I haven't come up with a solution. I have reverted my code back to its last (somewhat) working state for this question. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction from here.

questions.erb

```
<h1> this is the question page <h1>

<h2>meetup id </h2><%= @meetup_id %>
<br>

<h2>UID</h2><%= @user.uid %>
<br>
<h2>EID</h2><%= @event.id %>
<br>  
  <%= @questions.each do |q| %>  

      <%=q.poll%>

      <%= form_for (Answer.create), :remote => true do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :event, :value => params[:id]  %>     
          <%= f.hidden_field :user, :value => current_user.id %>
          <%= f.text_field :response %>
          <%= f.submit %>     
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

controller section

```
 def question
     @event = Event.find(params[:id])
     @questions = Question.all
 end
```

routes

```
resources :answers

resources :questions

 devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}, controllers:     {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}

 root 'home#index'
 get 'users/new', to: 'users#new'
 post 'users/new', to: 'users#create'
 get 'events/favorite', to: 'events#favorite', via:[:get], as: 'favorite'
 resources :events, only: [:index, :show]

 get 'events/form/:id' => 'questionss#new'

 patch 'events/:id' => 'events#index'

 post 'event/update' => 'events#update'

 get 'events/question/:id' => 'events#question'
```

Models

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user_id
    has_one :question_id
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_id, allow_destroy: true
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :questions
end 

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user_id
 has_and_belongs_to_many :answers
 belongs_to :event_id
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Thanks

Comment: whats the actual problem?

Comment: haha yeah looks like i forgot about that, at this point the problem is that I am getting multiple submit buttons, and i need to get one that submits all the answers to the questios.

Comment: First of all your models are wrong, you must use `has_one :user` and so on. And your form is inside the `each` loop which creates multiple submit buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many issues to detail properly; here's how to get it working:

--

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
root 'home#index'

devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}, controllers:     {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}

resources :answers
resources :users, only: [:new, :create]

resources :questions do
   resources :answers #-> domain.com/questions/1/answers/new
end

resources :events, only [:index, :new, :show, :update] do
   patch ":id", action: :index
   collection do
       get :favorite
       get "question/:id", action: :question
   end
end
```

As Rails' routing structure [is based around `resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), you *really* need to ensure every route is declared *around* the different objects in your app. More info here

--

**Models**

```
#app/models/answer.rb
Class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | user_id | question_id | other | attributes | created_at | updated _at
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :question
end

#app/models/event.rb
Class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | user_id | event | attributes | created_at | updated _at
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :questions
end

#app/models/question.rb
Class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | user_id | event_id | question | attributes | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :event

   has_many :answers
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Further reference - you should read up on [`foreign_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in regards to the formation of a relational database structure. This is super important, as when you declare [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark), you reference the `model`, not the `foreign_key`, as you have done.

--

**Controllers**

```
#app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
Class AnswersController < ApplicationController
    def new
       @question = Question.find params[:question_id]
       @answer = Answer.new
    end

    def create
        @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
        @answer.save
    end

    private

    def answer_params
       params.require(:answer).permit(:your, :answer, :params, :question_id)
    end
end
```

The reason I have used `answers_controller` is because `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is really only required if you create a new object (and want to save child objects through it).

As you're looking to create an `Answer` independently to a `Question`, I'd just use a [nested route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) to reference the question in the answer creation process:

--

**View**

Finally, you need to be able to then create the `Answer` in your view.

Here's how:

```
#app/views/answers/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@question, @answer] do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :answer_params %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Because you've used a nested object in the `form_for` helper, the system will build the routes to your `question_answer_path` - not just answer path; thus providing access to the `question` object in your creation process

---

**Object Orientated**

Finally, you need to be sure about how Rails works

Rails is built on top of Ruby. Ruby is an [`object orientated`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language - meaning that *everything* you do in Ruby revolves around "objects":

[image]

Translated into Rails, it means that every association, SQL query & other functionality will be directly related to the structure of your objects. If you ever get confused about how to integrate functionality into your app, always remember the object-orientated structure of the system